# Proper way to plot shapes/parametric equations with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am new at Python for plotting things, and I am wondering what would be the best way to plot the following figure?

[image: Shape (2 semi-circles and 1 cylinder)]

Basically, I'm trying to plot a shape with certain dimensions (2 semi-circles touching a cylinder in the middle (from point 2 to 3))
Let's say I have access to R2,R3, and the height of M3 point). With this known I tried to plot using parametric equations (x=R.cos(theta), y=r.sin(theta)) for the circles. I used 3D parametric from matplotlib and ended up have one circle. [EDIT] So far it's on a good way to be solved but I am feeling that there must be a better solution to this problem.

But I'm wondering if it's the best approach. I have read online that you can use shape files from the map community for example.

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


R2=3
r3=2
xp3=1

xp2=R2-np.sqrt(R2**2-r3**2)
hz=xp3-xp2

print ' -- Values --'
print 'R2: ',R2
print 'r3: ',r3
print 'xp3: ',xp3
print 'xp2: ',xp2
print 'hz: ',hz

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
theta = np.linspace(-4 * np.pi, 4 * np.pi, 100)
#z = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
z = 0
r = R2
x = r * np.sin(theta)
y = R2 + r * np.cos(theta)
ax.plot(x, y, label='test')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: exemple]

What would be your advice on that?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you saying that you solved your problem but are not sure if that's the best approach?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll edit my question. I'm on the way of solving that but I'm feeling that there must be a better solution, easier.